# jquery function inside pageload function fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a small jquery function that opens a popup window.

As my site is asp.net based and uses update panels, I place the function inside of the ajax pageLoad() function, to ensure it works after each postback.

I'm developing a new page with a number of update panels. If, after I've made several asynch postbacks, I then click on the hyperlink with the popup, the function seems to fire once for each postback that has occurred.

Here's the function:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $("a.popup").click(function (e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
        window.open(this.href, this.target, 'menubar=0, toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=1010, height=640, left=50, top=50');
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss to how to stop this happening. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler is getting re-bound every time the page load happens. Try this:

```
$("a.popup").unbind('click').click(function (e) {
```